# How to access code behind onclick function when launced page from mvc

Tags: asp.net, events, webforms, click

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNewDesi" runat="server" Text="New Item" OnClick="btnNewDesi_Click" />


public ActionResult PostJob()
    {
        return View("PostJob");
    }

 protected void btnNewDesi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {}
```

above I am launching postjob page from controller but Postjob is an aspx page.it has a codebehind file which inherits ".cs" page.
in post job i have place btnNewDesi Button.

Can you please help me in how to fire button click event when aspx page is launched from mvc ??

Comment: You can't mix mvc and webforms in one page

Comment: You can try below
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnNewDesi").trigger("click");
});

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin i am not mixing mvc and webforms.i am just launching the aspx page through controller and all the events for the respective aspx page is in the codebehind(aspx.cs)                          public ActionResult PostJob()
    {
        return View("PostJob");
    }

Comment: You ARE mixing MVC and WebForms. `public ActionResult PostJob()` is MVC, `protected void btnNewDesi_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` is WebForms